# spark dataframe mode overwrite duplicating the data into the table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hbase

I have df with updated data. i'm trying to overwrite df data in the table. but mode("overwrite") doing multiple entries into the table. please help

Old data in the Table

```
id number
1   1000
2   2000
3   3000
```

Updated data in dataframe :

```
id  number
1  5000
2  7000
3  3000
```

the statement I'm using for updating data into table is:

```
df.write.format(org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase) \
            .mode(saveMode).option("charset", "UTF-8").option("encoding", "utf-8").options(catalog=self.writeCatalog, newtable=5).save()
```

Comment: if it is hbase you can use append, if key exist it will overwrite automatically ?

Comment: Hi Srinivas thanks for quick reply. i even used append it is also not updating the record. it is added the record to the existing record. like Id 1 haves two values 1000 and  5000

Comment: in that case is id primary key in hbase ?